# Javascript mongoose callback function when set data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hello my problem is when I post base 64 images, I want to return a photo URL that's inside of my schema set return value

It always returns null and not set to photoUrl column

here is my schema

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        default: require('mongodb').ObjectID
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "country can't be null"]
    },
    photoUrl: {
        type: String,
        set: setImage
    }
})
```

this my setter function

```
function setImage(base64) {
    return uploadImage(base64,'/storage/products/');
}
```

and this is my uploadImage function on another page

```
const fs = require('fs');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

module.exports = {
    get: function() {
        let a = "Hello Node World!!!";
        return a;
    },
    uploadImage: function(base64,storageURI,callback) {
        const storagePathURI = '.' + storageURI;
        mkdirp(storagePathURI, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                var base64Data = base64.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");  
                fs.writeFile(storagePathURI + uuidv4() + '.png', base64Data, 'base64')
                return keys.baseStorageURI + storageURI +  uuidv4() + '.png'; 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

how can I map this URL to my photoUrl column when I insert or update the object?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Buffer` type as your Data Type in your Schema declaration instead of `String`?  Base-64 is considered to be a Buffer type, not a UTF-8 type as are Strings in JS.

Comment: But methods its works great just must be return string

Comment: My returned string is path location its no problem with upload image

Comment: İjust want to return the path location and set this